# NoClassDefFoundError and current locale in windows

Tags: java, windows, locale

So I have such class:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {}
}
```

I work on Windows 7 and I've changed current locale to English (USA).
When I run this class on path such C:\Москва I have error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Main
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: Main.  Program will exit.
```

When I run this class on path such C:\Moscow I have no errors and it works.
If my locale Russian everything is OK.

Please help me to understand. Why this happens.

Comment: java -cp . Main. Please notice that problem is not associate with classpath because <<java -cp . Main>> is invoked in Russian locale very well. I think that problem is related to path with cyrillic symbols and non-Russian locale in Windows.

Comment: Looking at this http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=184513 it seems it's a problem with windows and Java, but it's an old one: what version of Java are you using? Can you try with Java 7?

Answer (score 0):

C:\Москва is this folder in CLASSPATH? I suspect it is not. `NoClassDefFoundError` happens if a class was not available in java classpath during runtime. Add that folder to classpath. Here is good link on why this happens and what you need to do. [NoclassDefFoundError](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/06/noclassdeffounderror-exception-in.html)

Comment: yes in classpath. But the problem is not in classpath. It is locale issue under Windows.

Comment: I don't think so, if that is the case, it wouldn't show java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Main
Your stack trace has no clue related to locale.

Comment: Can you change your locale to Russian and run this class from path C:\Москва (or choose another cyrillic name of folder)? Please give results. Thanks.

Comment: `NoClassDefFoundError` is also thrown if `java` cannot find the class; since I suppose his test class is rather basic, it hardly is a problem with classpath.